# If cell value matches a UserForm ComboBox column, then copy to sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

What I am trying to do is :

1. loop through Column Q on Sheet "Global" starting at row 3
2. For every cell match value to UserForm ComboBox2 Column2, and the copy the entire row to the relevant sheet from userform2 coloum1.
3. loop though until last row. There could be several unique values in Column Q but will all be in the Userform2's Combobox2 columns.

I have no code as an example as I have no idea where to even begin!

This is my comboxbox, as is displays, on the backing of it each item have the below code, so a name, a code "2780" and a reference "BRREPAIRS".

```
.AddItem "Repairs"
ComboBox2.List(13, 1) = "2780"
ComboBox2.List(13, 2) = "BRRPEAIRS"
```

[image]

I need it to loop through everycell on the global sheet in column G, then match the cell value to the combobox list item from column 2. Once it has found a match it uses the code from column 1 ie "2780" to copy the entire row to the sheet matching the code in column 1.

Hopefully i have explained it a little better.

Comment: Plz post your code, even if it is not working

Comment: @R3uK, hi, thats the problem, i dont have any code, i have no idea where i should start!!

Comment: so if I understand this correctly.. you want to populate some combobox with values that matches selected value from other combobox..? hell even screenshot of the userform vould help.. the only thing standing between your answer is your explanation. coding is never a problem

Comment: I understand I think.. so you will have many sheets yes? as many as options in combobox? so you want it to have a button and start the procedure based on what is chosen.. so I press the button and it takes value from second column.. looks for match in column G on the sheet.. if it finds match then copy the row to the sheet corresponding to the value on first column in userform?

Comment: @Lance Hi, yes there are many sheets! You are nearly there, i want to match column G on the Sheet to the second column from the combobox, then copy the row to the sheet corresponding to the value in column 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim findmatch As Object
    Dim lastcell As Integer

    Set findmatch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Global").Range("G:G").Find(What:=UserForm2.ComboBox2.column(1), LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not findmatch Is Nothing Then
    lastcell = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(UserForm2.ComboBox2.Value).Cells(100000, 7).End(xlUp).row 'here find a way to locate last cell in sheet that has your name.. it keeps returning me 1 but other than that it works fine
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(UserForm2.ComboBox2.Value).Range(Cells(lastcell, 1), Cells(lastcell, 40)) = Range(Cells(findmatch.row, 1), Cells(findmatch.row, 40)).Value
    Else
    MsgBox "not found"
    End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, it gives me a Run-time error '381': Could not get the coloum property. Invalid property array index??

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to get it to work with the following code below. It looks for the correct cell in the combobox. Then copies it to the correct sheet in the correct position.

The only problem is that it runs very slowley!! Can anyone suggest some way of speeding it up?

And the last question is, having error handling for if a sheet doesn't exists, it tell you to create the sheet, or even create the sheet for you??

I really appreciate all the help guys, have been bashing my head on the wall for days!!!

```
Dim i, lastD, lastG As Long
Dim j As Integer
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .CutCopyMode = False
End With

' find last row
lastG = sheets("Global").Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).row

For i = 3 To lastG
    lookupVal = sheets("Global").Cells(i, "Q") ' value to find
    ' loop over values in "details"
    For j = 0 To Me.ComboBox2.ListCount - 1
        currVal = Me.ComboBox2.List(j, 2)
        If lookupVal = currVal Then
        sheets("Global").Cells(i, "Q").EntireRow.Copy
        sheets(Me.ComboBox2.List(j, 1)).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Insert shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next j
Next i

 With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .CutCopyMode = True
End With
```