# Error handling for if sheets exists when copying rows

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, excel-2010

following my post [If cell value matches a UserForm ComboBox column, then copy to sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33693909/if-cell-value-matches-a-userform-combobox-column-then-copy-to-sheet/33695775#33695775).

I have managed to get the code to work to move the check the names and move then to the correct sheets.

The problem i am having is checking if the sheets exists. If it finds a match in the sheet and column 2 in the combobox but there is no sheet for the value then it crashes the code.

2. Once all the information has been copied to the relevant sheets, i would like it to display a msgbox telling the user how many rows of data have been copied to the respective sheets.

   ```
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastG As Long, strWS As String, rngCPY As Range

   With Application
   .ScreenUpdating = False
   .EnableEvents = False
   .CutCopyMode = False
   End With

   On Error GoTo bm_Close_Out

   ' find last row
   lastG = sheets("Global").Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).row

   For i = 3 To lastG
       lookupVal = sheets("Global").Cells(i, "Q") ' value to find
       ' loop over values in "details"
       For j = 0 To Me.ComboBox2.ListCount - 1
           currVal = Me.ComboBox2.List(j, 2) ' value to match
           If lookupVal = currVal Then
               Set rngCPY = sheets("Global").Cells(i, "Q").EntireRow
               strWS = Me.ComboBox2.List(j, 1)
               On Error GoTo bm_Need_Worksheet  '<~~ if the worksheet in the next line does not exist, go make one
               With Worksheets(strWS)
                   rngCPY.Copy
                   .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Insert shift:=xlDown
               End With
           End If
       Next j
   Next i

   GoTo bm_Close_Out

   bm_Need_Worksheet:
   On Error GoTo 0
   With Worksheet
   Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet: Set wsTemplate = wb.sheets("Template")
   Dim wsPayment As Worksheet: Set wsPayment = wb.sheets("Payment Form")
   Dim wsNew As Worksheet
   Dim lastRow2 As Long
   Dim Contract As String: Contract = sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9").value
   Dim SpacePos As Integer: SpacePos = InStr(Contract, "- ")
   Dim Name As String: Name = Left(Contract, SpacePos)
   Dim Name2 As String: Name2 = Right(Contract, Len(Contract) - Len(Name))

   Dim NewName As String: NewName = strWS
   Dim CCName As Variant: CCName = Me.ComboBox2.List(j, 0)

   Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = wsPayment.Range("U36:U53").End(xlDown).row

   If InStr(1, sheets("Payment Form").Range("A20").value, "THE VAT SHOWN IS YOUR OUTPUT TAX DUE TO CUSTOMS AND EXCISE") > 0 Then
   lastRow2 = wsPayment.Range("A23:A39").End(xlDown).row
   Else
   lastRow2 = wsPayment.Range("A18:A34").End(xlDown).row
   End If

   wsTemplate.Visible = True
   wsTemplate.Copy before:=sheets("Details"): Set wsNew = ActiveSheet
   wsTemplate.Visible = False

   If InStr(1, sheets("Payment Form").Range("A20").value, "THE VAT SHOWN IS YOUR OUTPUT TAX DUE TO CUSTOMS AND EXCISE") > 0 Then
   With wsPayment
       For Each cell In .Range("A23:A39")
           If Len(cell) = 0 Then
               If sheets("Payment Form").Range("A20").value = "Network" Then
                   cell.value = NewName & " - " & Name2 & ": " & CCName
               Else
                   cell.value = NewName & " - " & Name2 & ": " & CCName
               End If
               Exit For
           End If
       Next cell
   End With
   Else
   With wsPayment
       For Each cell In .Range("A18:A34")
           If Len(cell) = 0 Then
               If sheets("Payment Form").Range("A20").value = "Network" Then
                   cell.value = NewName & " - " & Name2 & ": " & CCName
               Else
                   cell.value = NewName & " - " & Name2 & ": " & CCName
               End If
               Exit For
           End If
       Next cell
   End With
   End If

   If InStr(1, sheets("Payment Form").Range("A20").value, "THE VAT SHOWN IS YOUR OUTPUT TAX DUE TO CUSTOMS AND EXCISE") > 0 Then
   With wsNew
       .Name = NewName
       .Range("D4").value = wsPayment.Range("A23:A39").End(xlDown).value
       .Range("D6").value = wsPayment.Range("L11").value
       .Range("D8").value = wsPayment.Range("C9").value
       .Range("D10").value = wsPayment.Range("C11").value
   End With
   Else
   With wsNew
       .Name = NewName
       .Range("D4").value = wsPayment.Range("A18:A34").End(xlDown).value
       .Range("D6").value = wsPayment.Range("L11").value
       .Range("D8").value = wsPayment.Range("C9").value
       .Range("D10").value = wsPayment.Range("C11").value
   End With
   End If

   wsPayment.Activate

   With wsPayment
       .Range("J" & lastRow2 + 1).value = 0
       .Range("L" & lastRow2 + 1).Formula = "=N" & lastRow2 + 1 & "-J" & lastRow2 + 1 & ""
       .Range("N" & lastRow2 + 1).Formula = "='" & NewName & "'!L20"
       .Range("U" & lastRow + 1).value = NewName & ": "
       .Range("V" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & NewName & "'!I21"
       .Range("W" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & NewName & "'!I23"
       .Range("X" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & NewName & "'!K21"
   End With
   End With

   On Error GoTo bm_Close_Out
   Resume

   bm_Close_Out:

   With Application
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .EnableEvents = True
   .CutCopyMode = True
   End With
   ```

With help from Jeeped I have manage to get the code for copying the rows to the relevant sheets, and if the sheet doesn't exists then it create it. I just need help with problem two above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempting to use a [Worksheet Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194464.aspx) that does not exist throws an error. If you catch that error and create a worksheet with the name that you are looking for, you can `Resume` back to the point where the error was thrown and continue your processing.

```
Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastG As Long, strWS As String, strMSG As String
    dim rngHDR as range, rngCPY aS range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    On Error GoTo bm_Close_Out

    ' find last row
    lastG = Sheets("Global").Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To lastG
        lookupVal = Sheets("Global").Cells(i, "Q") ' value to find
        ' loop over values in "details"
        For j = 0 To Me.ComboBox2.ListCount - 1
            currVal = Me.ComboBox2.List(j, 2) ' value to match
            If lookupVal = currVal Then
                set rngHDR = Sheets("Global").Cells(1, "Q").EntireRow
                set rngCPY = Sheets("Global").Cells(i, "Q").EntireRow
                strWS = Me.ComboBox2.List(j, 1)
                On Error GoTo bm_Need_Worksheet  '<~~ if the worksheet in the next line does not exist, go make one
                With WorkSheets(strWS)
                     rngCPY .copy
                    .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Insert shift:=xlDown
                End With
                exit for
            End If
        Next j
        if j >= Me.ComboBox2.ListCount then _
            strMSG = strMSG & "Not found: " & lookupVal & chr(10)
    Next i

GoTo bm_Close_Out      

bm_Need_Worksheet:
    On Error GoTo 0
    With Worksheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        .Name = strWS
        'maybe make a header row here; watch out you do not lose your copy
        rngHDR.copy destination:=.cells(1, 1)
    End With
    On Error GoTo bm_Close_Out
    Resume

bm_Close_Out:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End With
    debug.print strMSG 
    'the next is NOT recommended as strMSG could possibly be VERY long
    'if cbool(len(strMSG)) then msgbox strMSG 
End Sub
```

There is a question about whether the new worksheet needs a column header label row but that should be fairly easily rectified.

Comment: this works well with creating the new sheet. The problem i have is that when i modified the code i use for creating a new sheets, it looses the copy, how can i get around this??

Comment: dim a range type var and `Set rng = <copy area>`. Dim and set another if you want to copy the header. Once you are on the new or existing worksheet you can rng.copy destination:=<wherever>`.

Comment: that worked perfectly! except one thing, once the code has run it seems to stop the autoupdate on formulas within the document, i have to save it to get the formulas to load.

Comment: i sorted it out, was a simple fix lol. Do you have any idea on how to do the msgbox to display how many rows have been copied to each sheet and a total of rows copied?? thanks

Comment: Hi could you please help me with some error handling? im trying to get it to display a msgbox if lookupVal <> currVal. The problem is i have put it after bm_Close_Out:, but it displays the message even when there is a matching value?? it has really got me stumped!!!!

Comment: The best place to check would be to compare the value of `j` to Me.ComboBox2.ListCount as soon as you exit the `For j=0` loop. However, you do not exit the loop when you find a match so it **always** runs to the end. If you use `Exit For` when you find a match then immediately after `Next j` the `j` var will be `< Me.ComboBox2.ListCount`. If it isn't then you've run to the end without finding a match and should report it.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but could you show me where to place it in the code, as that has confused me! Thanks!!

Comment: It has never been stated whether or not you want to exit the check for a match when you find a match. That's why the code is the way it is. If you want to get out of the loop once you find the first match then you can report non-matches. If you always want to keep going to the end even if you find a match then some other method would have to be thought out.

Comment: i don'd mind, whatever is the easiest way, it can come out of the loop on the first match to report non-matches. As long as all the rows will still get copied. Would this also aid in producing a msgbox which reports what has been copied and where?

Comment: You don't seem to understand. This is not about whether you mind; it is about whether breaking out of the loop will harm other processes. It is not about what is the easiest way; it about what is the best way to run your code. I'm going to have to think about this.

Comment: Thank you very much, i really appreciate the assistance!!

Comment: I ran added the extra code you added then ran it, and it display a msgbox saying that all of them were not found?

Comment: Hi, i dont me to push you, but have you had a think about this? If the code could be run in a better way then im open to suggestions. I really appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like this :

```
Sub test_atame()
Dim Ws As Worksheet

Set Ws = Sheet_Exists(ThisWorkbook, "Sheet1")
Set Ws = Sheet_Exists(ActiveWorkbook, "Sheet1")

End Sub
```

Here is the function :

```
Public Function Sheet_Exists(aWorkBook As Workbook, Sheet_Name As String) As Worksheet
Dim Ws As Worksheet, _
    SExistS As Boolean

SExistS = False
For Each Ws In aWorkBook.Sheets
    If Ws.Name <> Sheet_Name Then
    Else
        SExistS = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next Ws

If SExistS Then
    Set Sheet_Exists = aWorkBook.Sheets(Sheet_Name)
Else
    Set Sheet_Exists = Nothing
    MsgBox "The sheet " & Sheet_Name & " wasn't found in " & aWorkBook.Name & vbCrLf & _
            "Break code to check and correct.", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a check like:

```
Public Function SheetExists(ByVal Book As Workbook, ByVal SheetName As String) As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
Dim wsTest As Worksheet
Set wsTest = Book.Worksheets(SheetName)
If Not wsTest Is Nothing Then SheetExists = True

End Function
```