# Error handling, copying rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Following my post here: [Error handling for if sheets exists when copying rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33733182/error-handling-for-if-sheets-exists-when-copying-rows/33733872?noredirect=1#comment55238208_33733872)

I am in dire need of assistance. I need help with getting the error handling to work.

1. I need it to display a msgbox with the lookupVal from the Global sheet if it cannot find it in ComboBox2 list.
2. Along with this piece of error handling, you i also ask for assistance in getting it to display a MsgBox once the code has finished running to show how many rows have been copied to each sheet and and total number of rows copied.

Something similar to below, and if it copied more rows to other sheets then it would state after 2555, and then tells me the sheets were nothing was copied to.

[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastG As Long, strWS As String, rngCPY As Range

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .CutCopyMode = False
End With

If Range("L9") = "" Then
    MsgBox "You can't Split the Jobs at this stage. " & vbLf & vbLf & "Please create the form for the Sub-Contractor First." & vbLf & vbLf & "Please press Display Utilities to create form.", vbExclamation, "Invalid Operation" '& vbLf & vbLf & "This operation is invalid."
    Exit Sub
End If
    On Error GoTo bm_Close_Out

    ' find last row
    lastG = sheets("Global").Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).row

    For i = 3 To lastG
        lookupVal = sheets("Global").Cells(i, "Q") ' value to find
        ' loop over values in "details"
        For j = 0 To UserForm2.ComboBox2.ListCount - 1
            currVal = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List(j, 0) ' value to match
            If lookupVal = currVal Then
                Set rngCPY = sheets("Global").Cells(i, "Q").EntireRow
                strWS = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List(j, 1)
                On Error GoTo bm_Need_Worksheet  '<~~ if the worksheet in the next line does not exist, go make one
                With Worksheets(strWS)
                    rngCPY.Copy
                    .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Insert shift:=xlDown
                End With
                '''' 
                  Code here for msgbox to say, lookupVal ie(ISLDAMAGE) is not in the 
                  list, please create the sheet manually then copy the rows accordingly
                ''''
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

GoTo bm_Close_Out

bm_Need_Worksheet:
    On Error GoTo 0
    With Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet: Set wsTemplate = wb.sheets("Template")
    Dim wsPayment As Worksheet: Set wsPayment = wb.sheets("Payment Form")
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow2 As Long
    Dim Contract As String: Contract = sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9").value
    Dim SpacePos As Integer: SpacePos = InStr(Contract, "- ")
    Dim Name As String: Name = Left(Contract, SpacePos)
    Dim Name2 As String: Name2 = Right(Contract, Len(Contract) - Len(Name))

    Dim NewName As String: NewName = strWS
    Dim CCName As Variant: CCName = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List(j, 2)

    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = wsPayment.Range("U36:U53").End(xlDown).row

If InStr(1, sheets("Payment Form").Range("A20").value, "THE VAT SHOWN IS YOUR OUTPUT TAX DUE TO CUSTOMS AND EXCISE") > 0 Then
    lastRow2 = wsPayment.Range("A23:A39").End(xlDown).row
Else
    lastRow2 = wsPayment.Range("A18:A34").End(xlDown).row
End If

    wsTemplate.Visible = True
    wsTemplate.Copy before:=sheets("Details"): Set wsNew = ActiveSheet
    wsTemplate.Visible = False

If InStr(1, sheets("Payment Form").Range("A20").value, "THE VAT SHOWN IS YOUR OUTPUT TAX DUE TO CUSTOMS AND EXCISE") > 0 Then
    With wsPayment
        For Each cell In .Range("A23:A39")
            If Len(cell) = 0 Then
                If sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9").value = "Network" Then
                    cell.value = NewName & " - " & Name2 & ": " & CCName
                Else
                    cell.value = NewName & " -" & Name2 & ": " & CCName
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
Else
    With wsPayment
        For Each cell In .Range("A18:A34")
            If Len(cell) = 0 Then
                If sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9").value = "Network" Then
                    cell.value = NewName & " - " & Name2 & ": " & CCName
                Else
                    cell.value = NewName & " -" & Name2 & ": " & CCName
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cell
    End With
End If

If InStr(1, sheets("Payment Form").Range("A20").value, "THE VAT SHOWN IS YOUR OUTPUT TAX DUE TO CUSTOMS AND EXCISE") > 0 Then
    With wsNew
        .Name = NewName
        .Range("D4").value = wsPayment.Range("A23:A39").End(xlDown).value
        .Range("D6").value = wsPayment.Range("L11").value
        .Range("D8").value = wsPayment.Range("C9").value
        .Range("D10").value = wsPayment.Range("C11").value
    End With
Else
    With wsNew
        .Name = NewName
        .Range("D4").value = wsPayment.Range("A18:A34").End(xlDown).value
        .Range("D6").value = wsPayment.Range("L11").value
        .Range("D8").value = wsPayment.Range("C9").value
        .Range("D10").value = wsPayment.Range("C11").value
    End With
End If

wsPayment.Activate

    With wsPayment
        .Range("J" & lastRow2 + 1).value = 0
        .Range("L" & lastRow2 + 1).Formula = "=N" & lastRow2 + 1 & "-J" & lastRow2 + 1 & ""
        .Range("N" & lastRow2 + 1).Formula = "='" & NewName & "'!L20"
        .Range("U" & lastRow + 1).value = NewName & ": "
        .Range("V" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & NewName & "'!I21"
        .Range("W" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & NewName & "'!I23"
        .Range("X" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & NewName & "'!K21"
    End With
    End With

    On Error GoTo bm_Close_Out
    Resume

bm_Close_Out:

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .CutCopyMode = True
End With
End Sub
```

I have got this far with some help, but an failing at this last stage! All help is appreciated.

Comment: All that happens onerror is it goes to the label, where it turns screenupdating etc back on. Anything you need it to do needs to be after that label.

Comment: @Raystafarian Hi, i have tried putting some error handling after bm-Close_Out:. but it displays the msgbox even when there is a correct matching value. If i put a value that is not on the list then it displays the msgbox correctly, but if that is removed, it still displays it??

Comment: Right, because everything will always execute unless you exit the sub to avoid the error handler

Comment: @Raystafarian. i have managed to get if  lookupVal <> currVal then msgbox lookupVal. but it only displays the last non matching value. i need it to display all non matching value in one msgbox.

Comment: Then you're going to need a list or an array to put the values in, then display

Comment: @Raystafarian. could you please show me what code i would need for this. thanks

Comment: With your code, the error handling doesn't make sense. It'd basically be dim errList as string; if lookupval<>currval then errlist = errlist & " " & lookupval - then use `errlist` in the msgbox